# Python v344 error in google.com python 112345678

Tags: python

I While trying to use an old script I had for using the Google Drive python API, the authentication started to give me SSL errors. After a bit of investigation I narrowed the cause down to either the python requests module, or pyOpenSSL which it uses. I am able to show the problem with just this code:

```
import requests requests.get('https://google.com/')
```

The resulting error is, in full:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 444, in wrap_socket cnx.do_handshake() 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", 
line 1907, in do_handshake self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result) 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", 
line 1639, in _raise_ssl_error _raise_current_error() 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", 
line 54, in exception_from_error_queue raise exception_type(errors) OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", 
line 600, in urlopen chunked=chunked) 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", 
line 343, in _make_request self._validate_conn(conn) 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", 
line 849, in _validate_conn conn.connect() 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", 
line 356, in connect ssl_context=context) 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", 
line 359, in ssl_wrap_socket return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname) 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", 
line 450, in wrap_socket raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e) ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",) During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", 
line 445, in send timeout=timeout 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", 
line 638, in urlopen _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]) 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", 
line 398, in increment raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)) 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Email2notes\requtest.py", 
line 3, in <module> requests.get('https://google.com/') 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", 
line 72, in get return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs) 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", 
line 58, in request return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs) 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", 
line 512, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", 
line 622, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs) 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", 
line 511, in send raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

I think I can assume that Google's certs are ok, and the code is a single line, so I think the exception must be caused by one of the modules. I have seen other issues of this type that reccommend to update them (for example). However I already am using the latest version of requests and `urllib3` and `pyOpenSSL` (updated them using `pip`), I can't update them any further, so how might I fix this?

I have `requests[security]` installed as is suggested elsewhere. Also suggested there is to downgrade to an older version of certifi, but pip could not find the version suggested.

My python version is `3.5.0` and I'm working on `Windows 10`. Note that this is not a duplicate question; in other questions with this problem the issue was with the `website's SSL certs`. If there is a problem with Google's SSL certs that is beyond me.

Also, using `verify=False` does obviate this error for this snippet of code. However in my actual code (using `google-auth-oauthlib` which itself uses `requests`) there is nowhere for me to apply that - I just call e.g. `google_auth_oauthlib.flow.run_local_server()`, per here.

Comment: first edit question and use special function to format code and error message.

Comment: `pyOpenSSL` may need to update C/C++ library `OpenSSL` - and you can't do this with `pip` but you have to do it manually - download it from web page and install.